# How can I see memory usage history?

Tags: memory, ram, statistics

I am familiar with several commands like `top`, `htop`, `free`, etc. However, is there a command to see the peak/burst memory usage of the entire server (not individual processes) over, say, the last 30 days/24 hours/etc.?

Comment: The only solution I am aware of is to use a trending application stack, such as StatsD + Graphite.

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to collect these metrics.

[Sysstat](http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/documentation.html) may do this assuming you can define a couple crontabs.

Note that tools such as [Munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) or [Collectd](https://collectd.org/) are a couple popular solutions that would allow you to do this (while I wouldn't recommend Statsd/Graphite to newcomers, if at all).

Monitoring solutions such as [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net), [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com), Nagios (with perfdata, such as [Icinga](http://www.icinga.org) or [Shinken](http://shinken-monitoring.org)), or SNMP-based would also allow you to generate graphs from collected metrics.

We could also mention [Netdata](https://github.com/firehol/netdata): even though that one won't keep histories, it's still pretty helpful graphing instantaneous resources usages.

Comment: [Here's a fairly comprehensive list of metric collections tools.](http://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools.html) I believe StatsD and collectd are two of the more popular ones.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for "a command" (i.e. CLI), not GUI. Is there an equivalent? I'm fine with collecting metrics and saving them, but I just want the data, not all the fluff.

Answer (score 8):

`atop` tracks historical metrics and is command line based.

It's packaged in Debian/Ubuntu and Fedora.

https://www.atoptool.nl/index.php

Comment: It's not obvious how to use this `atop` tool to track memory usage OVER TIME.  It just shows a big list of processes and their current memory use.